# While Loop Breaks With Char

Tags: c

I have the following C code

```
int selectTask = 1;
while (selectTask > 0 && selectTask < 7) {
  printf("Please input which task to test: ");
  scanf("%d", &selectTask);
}
```

This works as intended until I input a char instead of a number, it then just loops my printf infinitely. Does anyone know why it does this?

Comment: Add a breakpoint , start debugging and examine selectTask closely. This also serves as usecase to encourage sanitization of user supplied values.  :)

Comment: You shall not ignore return values of library functions. There is a purpose why `scanfs` returns an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` works off of a line buffer. If the buffer is exhausted, it takes a new line; but if there's still things in the buffer, it does not actually take new input.

Also, `scanf` consumes exactly what you tell it to. If you want a number, it will consume a number, or fail. The return value of `scanf` is the number of things that it consumed successfully.

Thus, what happens is, your first `scanf` reads a new line (since it has nothing in the buffer); if the first character happens to not be a number, it will not consume anything and leave the buffer as is, and return `0` as "zero things successfully consumed". Next time you ask for a number, it will see that same character, and fail again, and again not consume anything. It's like it has this character stuck in its throat.

You can get around it by reading the rest of the buffer on failure, `fflush`-ing the buffer, reading a string and parsing it yourself... or, since you just need one character, give up `scanf` and just use `getchar`.

tl;dr: Don't ignore `scanf` return value :)